# Test if a class contains an instance variable based on its name

Tags: java, class

Sometimes I need to test which class has declared some variable(s), is there another way how to test that, if concrete class contains variable with some name

```
try {
   testLocalVariable = (String) (this.getClass().getDeclaredField("testVariable").get(this));
} catch (NoSuchFieldException ex) {
} catch (SecurityException ex) {
} catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
} catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
}
```

Comment: Can you give a little more background/context about the underlying problem you're trying to solve, as opposed to how you're trying to solve it? Also, are you looking for whether there's a member field with some name and type, or do you want to check equality of some instance as well?

Comment: What you described is pretty much the way to do it. However the scenario sounds a bit fishy. You can have legitimate reasons for doing what you're doing but 9 times out of 10 this pattern is the result of poor OO design.

Comment: you could to it this way. dont forget to check super classes using getField() or recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you use this code in a superclass to test if a subclass has a `testVariable` field.

Why don't you simply add a method like this?

```
 /**
  * Returns true if the object declares a testVariable field, false otherwise. Subclasses should
  * override this method
  */
protected boolean hasTestVariableField() {
    return false;
}
```

Seems much more OO to me, doesn't break encapsulation.

That said, I've not really understood why you needed this in the first place.

Comment: data are stored (last knows and consist...) in Database, and for debuging I really don't want to jumping between classes (voids ... whatever..) then I wrote a few shortcuts

Comment: I forgot answer to "Why don't you simply add a method like this?" because there I needed set/get value :-)

Answer (score 2):

Classes have fields, not local variables.

You can use `getDeclaredField()` however this will not find fields declared by super classes.

You don't need lookup the fields value, if you don't get an exception the field is there.

Comment: thanks for Field..., there isn't problem set/get/check if exist, my question is if there isn't (in Java) another way, but I have for testing only value in String :-)