# Assigning variables with dynamic names in Java

Tags: java, variables, dynamic-variables

I'd like to assign a set of variables in java as follows:

```
int n1,n2,n3;

for(int i=1;i<4;i++)
{
    n<i> = 5;
}
```

How can I achieve this in Java?

Comment: Could you please clarify your question?

Comment: You need to do this for local variables?  Why not array elements?

Comment: @ Eng.Fouad : I want to access variables by their name dynamically.

Comment: @Ashish Anand are you meaning http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6629995/test-if-a-class-contains-an-instance-variable-based-on-its-name

Answer (score 126, accepted):

This is not how you do things in Java.   There are no dynamic variables in Java.  Java variables have to be declared in the source code<sup>1</sup>.

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, you should use an array, a `List` or a `Map`; e.g.

```
int n[] = new int[3];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    n[i] = 5;
}

List<Integer> n = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    n.add(5);
}

Map<String, Integer> n = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    n.put("n" + i, 5);
}
```

---

It is possible to use reflection to dynamically *refer to* variables that have been declared in the source code.  However, this **only** works for variables that are class members (i.e. static and instance fields).  It doesn't work for local variables.  See @fyr's "quick and dirty" example.

However doing this kind of thing unnecessarily in Java is a bad idea.  It is inefficient, the code is more complicated, and since you are relying on runtime checking it is more fragile.  And this is not "variables with dynamic names".  It is better described as dynamic access to variables with static names.

---

<sup>1 - That statement is slightly inaccurate.  If you use BCEL or ASM, you can "declare" the variables in the bytecode file.  But don't do it!  That way lies madness!</sup>

Comment: Thanx a lot, got what I was looking for. The last part(Map<String, integer> ).

Comment: It should be noted that even if it would be possible, it shouldn't be something you would actually do. You don't gain anything from it; you'll actually lose readability. If you want to link them, use a  `Map<String, T>` instead, don't start messing with your actual code.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel - That's what I meant by "madness" :-)

Answer (score 39):

If you want to access the variables some sort of dynamic you may use reflection. However Reflection works not for local variables. It is only applyable for class attributes.

A rough quick and dirty example is this:

```
public class T {
    public Integer n1;
    public Integer n2;
    public Integer n3;

    public void accessAttributes() throws IllegalArgumentException, SecurityException, IllegalAccessException,
            NoSuchFieldException {

        for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
            T.class.getField("n" + i).set(this, 5);
        }
    }
}
```

You need to improve this code in various ways it is only an example. This is also not considered to be good code.

Comment: Excellent when you need to convert Android's sensor event.values[] into a set of variables. event.values[] could have a length from 1 to 6 and it's handy to have it convert, in my case for an array-less json marshaling.

Answer (score 14):

What you need is named array. I wanted to write the following code:

```
int[] n = new int[4];

for(int i=1;i<4;i++)
{
    n[i] = 5;
}
```

Comment: Don't want to use arrays. I want to dynamically access the variables (n1,n2,n3) depending on some condition.

Answer (score 12):

You should use `List` or `array` instead

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(1);
list.add(2);
list.add(3);
```

Or

```
int[] arr  = new int[10];
arr[0]=1;
arr[1]=2;
```

Or even better

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
map.put("n1", 1);
map.put("n2", 2);

//conditionally get 
map.get("n1");
```

Answer (score 8):

*Dynamic Variable Names in Java*
There is no such thing.

In your case you can use array:

```
int[] n = new int[3];
for() {
 n[i] = 5;
}
```

For more general `(name, value)` pairs, use `Map<>`

Answer (score 6):

You don't. The closest thing you can do is working with Maps to simulate it, or defining your own Objects to deal with.

Answer (score 5):

Try this way:

```
    HashMap<String, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap();

    for (int i=1; i<=3; i++) {
        hashMap.put("n" + i, 5);
    }
```