# How to generate instance name dynamically?

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing, instance

I need to set the name of an instance of a class dynamically.

```
GetDataPoint "This Name has to be dinamically" = new GetDataPoint();
```

I need dynamic numbers of instances of this class GetDataPoint. Can anyone help please?

Comment: Arrays, Lists, Sets come to mind...

Comment: Yes use any `Collection` class and you want to associate any text,  use `setTag()`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6729645/1654265

Comment: @AndreaLigios: It seems you have good profile on stackoverflow, anything useful there for this Question?

Comment: Maybe if you describe your question more precisely, like why do you need that - the community will be able to help you more. I see "xml-parsing" as one of the tags in the question, so I wonder whether you should use a simple array as suggested, or you are trying to do something more complex

Comment: @MAC Nothing, apart from the Answer

Answer (score 1):

An example:

```
ArrayList<GetDataPoint> data = new ArrayList<GetDataPoint>();
int amountOfData = 5;

for(int i = 0; i <= amountOfData; i++) {
data.add(new GetDataPoint());
}
```

Loop over the data list to retrieve the GetDataPoints.