# how to declare an instance of a class with name created from concatenation

Tags: java, class, object, concatenation, instance

I want to declare a new instance of a class, but have the name created from concatenation.

eg.

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
     Class ('movement' + i) = new Class();

     switch(i) {

       case 0:
       movement0.stuff();
       break;

       case 1:
       movement1.stuff();
       break;

       case 2:
       movement2.stuff();
       break;
     }
  }
```

is this possible? I know this isn't the correct syntax, but it is me guessing

Comment: That's not declaring an instance, that's declaring a variable.

Comment: Can't do that in java.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? maybe there's a Java way to do what you want. ie using polymorphism perhaps?

Comment: @jb I found this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16171941/how-to-generate-instance-name-dynamically I'm trying to dynamically create instances as the for loop iterates

Comment: That's not a java feature. I think maybe php can do that? maybe? but its not a normal thing. Can you put stuff in a list? why do you want dynamically created instances?

Comment: @jb I could, it was just to try and make my code smarter. I wanted to have an object, then create new instances of said object as the for loop iterated

Comment: clever != better :) Sometimes writing the cleverest code you can makes it really hard to read and figure out what is going on. In this case, even if you could do it, the code would be really hard to read since you don't know what type each object is.