# How to rename or create a new String dynamically?

Tags: java, string

I have a bunch of strings with weird names (like this docFileeh934fhry) that contain text like this

`System.out.println(docFileeh934fhry);`

```
`.............document: 12345.....
...................
...............`
```

---

I want to rename these strings. So that the above string will be `String doc12345`

How can I do this?

---

I know how to get this number using `Pattern.compile`

Let's say I have this number `String docNumber = "12345";`

Now how can I dynamically create a new string?

I tried

`String doc+docNumber = docFileeh934fhry;` // no result

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic Variable Names in Java:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729605/dynamic-variable-names-in-java)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might be able to do this with reflection, but it has to be said that this is a very poor approach.

Your naming of variables should not depend on any external input. Instead, give it a name that describes its contents and go from there.

What do you gain by naming it `doc1`?

If you are looping trough files all you probably want is a `currentDocument`. Any other variables (`firstDocument`, `nextDocument`, `oldDocument`, etc) you name according to their *function*, not their contents.

If you want a way to uniquely identify the correct document, create a class instead

```
class Document {
   int id;
   string contents;
}
```

After storing all these `Document` objects into a collection (like an `ArrayList`), you can just retrieve the document you need on basis of that id rather than having to mess around with a bunch of generated variables.

Another point to note: how would you even use this when you have 50 documents? 100? 10.000? This would be impossible to maintain.

If you don't want to create a custom class you can go with the `HashMap<Integer, String>` route.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't how Java works. If you want to associate an object with a String, then use a Map such as a `HashMap<String, String>`.

Answer (score 3):

1. Assign the string to the variable w/ the new name.  Note that the new name will have to be have been defined when writing the code, it can't be computed on the fly (if that is what you are driving at).
2. You can't use `+` in a variable name.  As above, you can't make variable names on the fly.

Answer (score 3):

Here maybe one possible solution,use Hashmap,key is your varname(the way as you wish) and value is your string.