# Creating class in java (android) with a variable name

Tags: java, android, class

I have a program for Android with few classes.
In my MainActivity i am using those classes.
For example i have this class named Car.
and so in my main activity i put this code to make a new "car" object.

```
Car car = new Car();
```

Now i also have a variable called count. that always increment by one.
I want My main activity to create class every time (count%10 == 0).
with a name like that car10,car20,car30. The number changer as the counter changes too.
I did something like that and got stuck:

```
for(int i=0;i<100; i++)
{
if(i%10 == 0)
{
Car car+i = new Car();
}

}
```

but it didn't work. Any Idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assigning variables with dynamic names in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729605/assigning-variables-with-dynamic-names-in-java)

Comment: It's not the *class* that has a variable name, it's the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java you cannot have variable variable names.

Consider using an array or a list. For example:

```
List<Car> list = new ArrayList<Car>();

// ...

list.add(new Car());
```

or if you need to name the indices, use a map:

```
Map<String, Car> map = new HashMap<String, Car>();

// ...

map.put("car" + i, new Car());
```

Comment: Hey, hmm i have another class called Stop. and his parameters are (Car car) how do i get the car class name in it? from the map. cuz i can't use string. i need to use a variable that his type is Car