# declaring multiple java arrays in a loop

Tags: java, arrays, loops, dynamic, multidimensional-array

Hi guys thanks for helping in advance this is not the real code it is just the idea i want to reach

```
for (int i = 1, i< some number ; i ++ )

float  [][] sts + i = new float[9][9];
```

The idea is to have 2 dimensional arrays with dynamic names initializing in a loop

sts1 
sts2
sts3
.
.
.
.
.

Comment: Yeah you can't use dynamic names for variables in java, like you can in PHP. Just use array or ArrayList.

Comment: That's impossible I'm afraid. Just use a `float[][][]`.

Comment: If you want to keep reference names "sts"+i, one of the finest solutions is to use a HashMap<String, float[][]>. Eg yourMap.put("sts" + i, new float[9][9]);

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assigning variables with dynamic names in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729605/assigning-variables-with-dynamic-names-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your problem, where naming is sequential based on the value of `i`, an ArrayList could do the job as you can iterate over it.

However, a more general approach that enables you accessing your arrays by some String name (even if this was random and not sequential as in your case) would be to use a `Map<String, float[][]>`, where the key `String` of the `Map` is the name you have given to your array.

```
Map<String, float[][]> myMap = new HashMap<String, float[][]>();

for(int i = 0; i < someNumber; ++i)
{
    myMap.put("sts" + i, new float[9][9]);
}
```

then access each array by `myMap.get(_aName_);`

Comment: Yes that would be an alternative to my solution. If the names have a particular meaning, then I would also use the HashMap version.

Answer (score 1):

If you create every 2 dimensional array in the loop, then the variabl (like sts1) will only be local to the loop. So after the loop the variable is out of scope (but I think you want to use them after the loop, that's why you want different names). So to use the created variables, you have to use an array. And if you use an array, the question of naming ceases.

```
ArrayList<float[][]> l = new ArrayList<float[][]>();

for(int i = 0; i < someNumber; ++i)
{
    l.add(new float[9][9]);
}
```

Comment: thank you you are correct i will use this arrays globally to create time series

Answer (score 0):

You can't create variable names dynamically in Java. Just do this

```
float[][][] sts = new float[someNumber][9][9];
```

Then you can use `sts[0]`, `sts[1]` where you wanted to use `sts1`, `sts2` etc.