# How to create a new variable using old variable and assiging it some value in groovy

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to create a new variable using the name of old variable (appending old variable with some string) and assign that new variable with some value as in example below in jenkinsfile using groovy:

```
def var1= "value1"
def var1 + "_someval"= 50  // creating a new variable which will have name value1_someval and it will have value 50
print( "value for value1_someval  is" + value1_someval) 
// expected output is that new  variable value1_someval is created with value 50 assigned to it.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by using quoted identifies in following way:

```
def map = [:]
def lastchar = "_someval"

map."val1${lastchar}" = 50

//assert map.'val1_someval' == 50

print map.VA_REPOSITORY_VERSION
```

prints out 50 as output

Comment: I was going to suggest a map because you can name the keys what you want, but I thought it too far removed from your question, so I suggested a list.

Answer (score 1):

Whatyou want to do is [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37856831/3355860), but it's messy and can cause problems. I strongly suggest that you use a list instead:

```
List li = []
li[0] = "value1"
li[1] = 50
```