# How do you convert a string variable to a layout variable?

Tags: java, android, string, layout, casting

This is the section of code:

```
int buttonXa = 0, buttonXb = 4, layoutNum = (buttonXb - 1);
String layoutXNum = String.valueOf(layoutNum);
String layoutX;
LinearLayout layoutXab;
do {
    layoutX = "ll" + layoutXNum;
    layoutXab = (LinearLayout)layoutX;
    buildButtons(layoutXab, buttonXa, buttonXb);
    buttonXa += 4;
    buttonXb += 4;
    layoutNum += 1;
} while (buttonXa < 12);
```

Why doesn't the casting work? What is the correct code?HI there @J.Knight and any others This code is trying to send to the "build buttons" function, a linear layout, whose name is built dynamically within a "do while" loop, the first time the layout is called ll3 then ll4 and so on...The name was built and put into a String variable, but now needs to be converted to a Linear Layout variable... Thanks Emuna

Comment: What is the "casting" that doesn't work? Please show complete code and error message.

Comment: How does class hierarchy of those two have anything to do with each other, why would you want it to work?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? I can think of a few different things you might be trying to do here and reasons it can't be done this way but I would be wasting time by explaining each scenario. The casting is not the issue there, you have a bigger problem on your hands.

Comment: HI there @J.Knight and any others 

This code is trying to send to the "build buttons" function, a linear layout, whose name is built dynamically within a "do while" loop, the first time the layout is called ll3 then ll4 and so on...The name was built and put into a String variable, but now needs to be converted to a Linear Layout variable... 

Thanks
Emuna

Comment: Ahh ok, so this is not possible in Java. It might be worth reading this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729605/assigning-variables-with-dynamic-names-in-java

Comment: Thanks @J.Knight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `layoutX` is of type 'String'.
The variable `layoutXab` is of type 'LinearLayout'

A 'LinearLayout' is not a sub-type of 'String', nor is 'String' a sub-type of 'LinearLayout'.

Casting is a way of specialising or generalising a type, and neither of these two types are a specialisation of the other.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Get the ID for R.layout.button1 
int resID = context.getResources().getIdentifier("button1", "layout", context.getPackageName());
//context could be an object of Activity too
```

> Remember that this way is slower than directly using the resource ids,
>   especially when you have hundreds of such ids to convert from String
>   to int.

For more on Resource refer to this link https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html