# print many values by a loop in java

Tags: java

```
public class teste {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int t1=5;
    int t2=10;
    int t3=30;

    for(int i=1;i<4;i++)
    {
        System.out.println("t"+i);
    }

}}
```

Hi guys I don't know if it exists in java but I wanna print t1 t2 t3 by a loop, for example for i=1 t(i=1) => t1 so it will give us 5, how can I do that, and thank you all.

Comment: You want to use an array. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: You need to create an array like: `int[] t = {5. 10, 30, etc..}`

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729605/assigning-variables-with-dynamic-names-in-java

Comment: thanks I'm convinced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can `"t" + i` be considered a key (instead of a dynamic variable name which is not supported)?  If that fits the context then a Map could be used.  For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Integer> tVals = new HashMap<>();
    tVals.put("t1", 5);
    tVals.put("t2", 10);
    tVals.put("t3", 30);

    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        System.out.println(tVals.get("t" + i));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

3 variables mean three atomic statements are required but to access them in continuous way , collect them in some container like array so use

```
int t1=5;
int t2=10;
int t3=30;
int[] arr = {t1,t2,t3}; // array index start from 0
//           0  1  2
// arr[0] is 5
// arr[1] is 10 and so on

for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    System.out.println(arr[i]);
}
```

**Other option**: use var args which is still sort of an array but flexible like

```
static void printNums(int... arr){
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

and call it like

```
printNums(t1,t2);
printNums(t1,t2,t3);
printNums(1,2,3,4,5,6);
```

Comment: I know this method but I'm looking for others thank you

Comment: @AyoubEloumari what makes you think there are others?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to call a `variable` using `String` or `int` or whatever

But that's the purpose of `arrays`, first index is `0` and last one is `length-1 (here 2)`

```
int[] t = new int[]{5, 10, 30};

for(int i=0 ; i<t.length ; i++){
    System.out.println(t[i]);
}
// gives
5
10
30
```

Comment: I know this method but I'm looking for others thank you

Comment: @AyoubEloumari others ? With which specificities ?

Comment: like I told in the question above and also it exists in php

Comment: @AyoubEloumari Java is not PHP (thank the maker). There is no reason to assume that features in one language would exist in another.

Comment: @AyoubEloumari curious to know how PHP does that

Answer (score 0):

The for loop will only print the values t1, t2,t3 only because you initialized the t1 as a variable and in your output you using it as a text by including quotation marks.
Try this code.

```
public class test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] arrValue = {5 , 10 , 30};

        for(int i= 0; i <4; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("t"+i + "=" + arrValue[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Same answer as mine + will throw ArrayOutOfBoundsException ^^

Answer (score -1):

Please tell me if I don't understand your question.
What you seem to be trying is to print t1 t2 and t3, but based on the i of the for loop right? So you think that t + i should first be t1, then t2 then t3 and finally output those values. That doesn't work for any language this way. First of all, t is a char, while 1 2 or 3 is an integer. Secondly, if you put it like that in System.out.println it basically means "print out t and then i", instead of "print out what t+i would be (as initialized)". I might not be very clear with explaining. Anyway, you should use an array.

Try the following:

```
class test{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] anArray = { 
        5, 10, 30,
    };

        for(int i = 0; i < anArray.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(anArray[i]);

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I wrote this when nobody answered, i cant really do smth about the fact that everyone reacted at the same time. Secondly, this code is correct idk what ur talking about? Maybe learn java be4 talking
Also, some people's codes would give out of bound exception, mine doesnt