# JAVA: naming an array index

Tags: java

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QP1hS.png)Im trying to create an 8x8 array and i know that according to java that array[0][0] is the index of the first row, first column. I want to rename this to some name 'a1'
similary array[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QP1hS.png)[0] as 'a2'
         array[2][0] as 'a3'
The code below is what I want to do but I am not sure if there exists a syntax for that. Correct me if I'm wrong but if there is a chance to rename my array, that will make it so much easier for me. Thanks in advance.

```
char[][] cb;
char a=8;
char b=8;
cb= new char[a][b];
cb[0][0]=name('a1');
cb[1][0]=name('a2');
cb[2][0]=name('a3');
...
  ...
cb[5][7]=name('h6');
cb[6][7]=name('h7');
cb[7][7]=name('h8');


//Then I save some elements in each index with the new name
```

I've attached the chessboard image, I get an input as Rf1 which means my rook is at cell f1 but in array language its [7][5] right? So i want to know if I can do that change somehow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assigning variables with dynamic names in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729605/assigning-variables-with-dynamic-names-in-java)

Comment: Sounds like a **XY-problem**. Please clarify what you want to do with this, there's likely a way better approach.

Comment: If you're trying to name the variable itself, then no, this cannot be done. If you're trying to assign a char to the array that is not a char, then I have no idea what you're really trying to do.

Comment: You can't directly "rename" the cells of your array, but you _can_ turn your spreadsheet-like names into the corresponding pairs of integer subscripts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assigning variables with dynamic names in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729605/assigning-variables-with-dynamic-names-in-java)

Comment: edited the post now, please check image to understand my question better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make it so the variables in your code have those names, but what you can do is write a method that converts the string input, such as `f1` into the indexes required.  The basic approach is to separate the column (`a` through `g`) and rank (`1` through `8`) and then map those to row and column.  In the (pseudo-)code below I'll assume index `[0,0]` is at the bottom left, corresponding to the `a1` square.  The code assumes the input is a valid position and does not do any range checking, that is left to you.

```
public static class CellIndex {
    int row;  
    int col;
    public CellIndex(int row, int col) {
        this.row = row;
        this.col = col;
    }
    // getters, etc.
}
...
public CellIndex mapPositionToIndex(String position) {
    int col = (int)(position.charAt(0) - 'a');
    int row = (int)(position.charAt(1) - '1');
    return new CellIndex(row,col);
}
```

The `CellIndex` class encapsulates a row/column cell position in your array.

The method `mapPositionToIndex` takes in a string with a position designator and converts it to an array index.  Input `a1` converts to `[0,0]` and `h8` converts to `[7,7]`.  If you want to start with the top left corner you can adjust the calculation, but the principle is the same.

There are many other ways to approach this problem.  If you have classes`Board` and `Cell`, which model the board, you could have a `Board` method that returns the appropriate `Cell` object when given a position, hiding all the internal details from the users of the class, i.e.

```
Class Cell {
    // The model of a single cell on a chessboard
}
Class Board {
    ...
    public Cell getCell(String position) {
        // Interpret the position and return the corresponding Cell object
    }
    ...
}
```