# How to devine multiple variables in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to declare multiple global variables in Kotlin with names like vehicle1, vehicle2, vehicle3... using a loop.

I think this is how one would do it in C++ ->

```
for(i=0; i<10; i++){
   int vehicle[1];
}
```

Comment: Simply create an array list of vehicles why create dynamic variables?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729605/assigning-variables-with-dynamic-names-in-java

Comment: That C++ snippet would create a one-element array and immediately destroy it since it goes out of scope, 10 times.

Answer (score 0):

So you want an **Array** with 10 **Strings**, each one having different names right? You can do something like this:

```
val vehicles = emptyArray<String>()
for (i in 0 until 10) vehicles[i] = "vehicle$i"
```