# Creating multiple dataframes using 'for' loop in Java Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to create new dataframes using the columns of an initial dataframe (df0).

I tried to create an array of strings to use it for dataset names, but it didn't work.

```
String [] column = ds.columns();
String [] dsName = new String[10];
int max=ds.schema().length();
for (i=0; i<max; i++) {
        Dataset<Row> dsName[i]=null;
        for (j=0; j<max && j!=i; j++) {
            for (k=0; k<max && k!=i && k!=i; k++) {
                            dsName[i]= ds.select(ds.col(column[i]),
                                                ds.col(column[j]),
                                                ds.col(column[k]));

                       }
               }
}
```

Expected result for (initial df0, and 3 dfs df1i):

```
df11 = df0.select(df0.col("1"),df0.col("2"));
df12 = df0.select(df0.col("1"),df0.col("3"));
df13 = df0.select(df0.col("1"),df0.col("4"));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assigning variables with dynamic names in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729605/assigning-variables-with-dynamic-names-in-java)

Comment: It's easy to do for arrays, lists .. But I don't see how to  use the samething for dataframes. We cannot create an array of dataframes.

Comment: What is your ultime goal? This seems a little cumbersome. I never used an array of dataframes (I used maps in some occasion). Not saying you’re wrong, but maybe you can provide a little more...

Comment: Let's say we have a dataframe with 10 columns, the goal is to create multiple dataframes from each 3 columns in the initial dataframe.