# Target Variable based on String in Java

Tags: java

I need to allow the user to target a variable using a string name. Example,

```
int number = 5;

String variableTarget = "number";
```

I need to target the int, number, and then change its value in later code. Any way?

I cannot think of any way to do it. There seems to be alot of class targeting, but I already have that.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: What are you really trying to do? I doubt you need to do this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729605/assigning-variables-with-dynamic-names-in-java ?

Comment: Have you tested Reflection? https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reflection-in-java/

Comment: You could try a `Map` of name to value, instead of a real variable. `Map<String, Integer> variables = new HashMap<>(); variables.put("number", 5);`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is a way to do this in java. But, to have such a functionality, you can use a map to assign the value to the `number` key in the Map :

```
HashMap <String, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<>();
myMap.put("number", 5);
```

and you can alter the value later using the same `put` statment :

```
myMap.put("number", myMap.get("number")+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java Reflections, or create another structure like a HashMap answered by @DodgyCodeException