# How to name a Object in a loop?

Tags: java, loops, object

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  Ticket t1 = new Ticket();
}
```

I have created class `Ticket` and I need to create 10 tickets in a loop, but I have a problem with name for that object. In this code that I write above name for object is `t1`. I am wondering if there is a way to change this name every time when I'm creating new object in loop for.

Comment: i dont think so, but if you do need to refer to each Ticket separately, you could store the tickets in an arraylist or array, and refer to it using index

Comment: right. A quick search gave me this link which says: no, you cant assign dynamic variable names. https://stackoverflow.com/q/6729605/16034206

Comment: thats what arrays or other collections are for.

Comment: Dare I say you could if you could go completely meta and write a java program that generates java source code that creates the variables you need in a dynamic way and load it at runtime? But I would *not* advise that. There should be no need to do so as there are much more easier ways to do so.

Comment: Each pass through the loop, an object gets created, then never referenced outside of the loop. Why even bother naming the result of `new Ticket()`? How does the name matter at all?