# how to display variable name dynamic in java

Tags: java, string, variables

i want to display only the variable name not the value
let's say

```
String x='abc';
```

i want my output to be `x` not`abc`
don't want to create a code like this

```
System.out.println('x')
```

i want dynamicaly save the variable name in another variable and display it
like if there's a built in function to do this like for example i know this function doesn't exist but lets say it exists

```
System.out.println(x.getVariableName()) //output x
```

i want a something like that

Comment: Short answer: you can't, at least not for local variables. It's something that people are inclined to want to do when they start programming, and there is almost never a need for this. Check [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729605/assigning-variables-with-dynamic-names-in-java) for context. If you want to store key/value pairs, use a `HashMap`. By the way, `String x='abc';` is not valid Java.

Comment: I know i just wrote a dummy example for the sake of the question but thank u for ur clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. When you compile a java program in java bytecode, the information about variable names are not included.

For example:
File `Main.java`

```java
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String x = "abc";
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

compiled in `Main.class` (there are many more "characters" you cannot see):

```
Êþº¾   = 
      java/lang/Object <init> ()V  abc   
   
  java/lang/System out Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      java/io/PrintStream println (Ljava/lang/String;)V  Main Code LineNumberTable main ([Ljava/lang/String;)V 
SourceFile  Main.java !                    *· ±                    +     L²     +¶ ±
```

If you try to use a decompiler to decompile the bytecode, that's what you'd get:

```java
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] paramArrayOfString)
    {
        String str = "abc";
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

As you can see, there is no information about any variable names.

The simplest reason behind this is that this information is *completely useless to the runtime*, it is only useful to programmers when they're writing code, to give a meaning of what they're coding and keep track of the business logic.

Comment: ok i thought there's a way for that thank u for the clarification