# Is it possible to loop setters and getters?

Tags: java, loops, getter-setter

I'm fairly confident that there's no way this could work, but I wanted to ask anyway just in case I'm wrong:

I've heard many times that whenever you have a certain number of lines of very similar code in one batch, you should always loop through them.

So say I have something like the following.

```
setPos1(getCard1());
setPos2(getCard2());
setPos3(getCard3());
setPos4(getCard4());
setPos5(getCard5());
setPos6(getCard6());
setPos7(getCard7());
setPos8(getCard8());
setPos9(getCard9());
setPos10(getCard10());
setPos11(getCard11());
setPos12(getCard12());
```

There is no way to cut down on lines of code as, e.g., below, right?

```
for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
setPos + i(getCard + i)());
}
```

I'm sure this will have been asked before somewhere, but neither Google nor SO Search turned up with a negative proof.

Thanks for quickly confirming this!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6629995/test-if-a-class-contains-an-instance-variable-based-on-its-name

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No way to do that specifically in Java without reflection, and I don't think it would be worth it. This looks more like a cue that you should refactor your getcard function to take an integer argument. Then you could loop.

Comment: Most definitely right about refactoring the functions to take integer arguments. There is no way on earth that having two sets of twelve practically-identical functions makes sense.

Comment: I agree that this seems like bad design. Most probably `pos` and `card` are collections or arrays and thus a getter and setter with an additional index would be way better.

Comment: Ah, never thought about that. Thanks for the hint. Having had a first look at reflection, I agree that this would be shooting cannons at sparrows (as they say in Germany).

Comment: @baphomet13 - I assume you have seen this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=63Y5XjlO4vk

Answer (score 4):

This is a simple snippet that shows how to loop through the getters of a certain object to check if the returned values are null, using reflection:

```
for (Method m : myObj.getClass().getMethods()) {
    // The getter should start with "get" 
    // I ignore getClass() method because it never returns null
    if (m.getName().startsWith("get") && !m.getName().equals("getClass")) {
            // These getters have no arguments
            if (m.invoke(myObj) == null) {
                // Do something
            }
    }
}
```

Like the others stated, probably it's not an elegant implementation. It's just for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 3):

You could do it via reflection, but it would be cumbersome.  A better approach might be to make generic setPos() and getCard() methods into which you could pass the index of the current item.

Comment: +1: The fact that you want to set values like this is an indication that having a set/get for each specific value is not a good design for your needs.

Answer (score 2):

You need to ditch the getter/setter pairs, and use a `List` to store your objects rather then trying to stuff everything into one God object.

Here's a contrived example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Foo {
    public static class Card {
        int val;

        public Card(int val) {
            this.val = val;
        }

        public int getVal() {
            return val;
        }

    }

    public static class Position {
        int value;

        public Position(Card card) {
            this.value = card.getVal();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>(Arrays.asList(new Card(1), new Card(2), new Card(3)));
        List<Position> positions = new ArrayList<Position>();
        for (Card card : cards) {
            positions.add(new Position(card));
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can't dynamically construct a method name and then invoke it (without reflection).  Even with reflection it would be a bit brittle.

One option is to lump all those operations into one method like `setAllPositions` and just call that method.

Alternatively, you could have an array of positions, and then just loop over the array, setting the value at each index.

`Card[] cardsAtPosition = new Card[12];`

and then something like

```
public void setCardsAtEachPosition(Card[] valuesToSet) {
   // check to make sure valuesToSet has the required number of cards
   for (i = 0; i < cardsAtPosition.length; i++) {
       cardsAtPosition[i] = valuesToSet[i];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reflection would be your only option for your example case.