# Is there a library which can identify the Swing GUI components within a java class?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I would like to be able to identify the GUI components with a class. So for example if class GUI,  which extends JFrame, has a JButton component and Jpassword component, I need to be able to know that these two components are within this class, and possibly in which methods they are used.

The only idea I can think of to be able to acquire this information is parsing. Does anyone know of a library which is able to extract this kind of information from the Java source code file please?

Comment: If you want to retrieve all the components included in a JFrame, you can use `getComponents()` recursively. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495769/how-to-get-all-elements-inside-a-jframe

Comment: I am not allowed to modify the code in the GUI class... as this will be given to me by some other developer... and I think it would be very messy to instantiate these classes to get this information

Answer (score 2):

Part of methods is possible by implements [Reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/), maybe my [question will help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6629995/test-if-a-class-contains-an-instance-variable-based-on-its-name)

Comment: I will have no idea of the names of the declared field... so I dont think that I can used the results your question... i will take a look at reflection though... thanks

Comment: @ict1991 on this forum is a few good threads about that, be sure that JButton or JPasswordTextField is same Object as whatever another declared in Java

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to leverage the output produced by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, as described in [*Swing testing and debugging*](https://community.oracle.com/blogs/alexfromsun/2006/06/28/swing-testing-and-debugging-javaone). Also useful in this context is a tool to detect event dispatch thread violations, recapitulated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7788806/230513).

Comment: The URL for "*Swing testing and debugging*" doesn't work anymore. (Java.net is no longer operational)

Comment: @StevenVascellaro: Thanks for the heads up; links updated.