# Can you reference a java variable from a string?

Tags: java, cookies, dictionary

Hi I have a strange question about java.  I will leave out the background info so as not to complicate it.  If you have a variable named fname.  And say you have a function returning a String that is "fname".  Is there a way to say reference the identifier fname via the String "fname".  The idea would be something like "fname".toIdentifier() = value but obviously toIdentifier isn't a real method.

I suppose a bit of background mite help.  Basically I have a string "fname" mapped to another string "the value of fname".  And I want a way to quickly say the variable fname = the value of the key "fname" from the map.  I'm getting the key value pair from iterating over a map of cookies in the form .  And I don't want to do "if key = "fname" set fname to "value of fname" because I have a ton of variables that need to be set that way.  I'd rather do something like currentkey.toIdentifer = thevalue.  Weird question maybe I'm overlooking a much easier way to approach this.

Comment: [yes is possible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6629995/test-if-a-class-contains-an-instance-variable-based-on-its-name) , but its for testing, there are a few good ways, this question talking about wrong desing

Comment: It seems like you just want a Map: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html _OR_ you might want to look into reflection.... _OR_ you might want to think about your design a bit.

Comment: I agree the design is probably flawed but I had never thought about doing something like that.

Comment: I'm pretty certain I don't understand the question.  A little more explanation would help...

Comment: @jahoy...ya thats why originally I was going to leave out the details.  The question is essentially, given a string, can I set a variable whose identifier is equal to that string by using the actual String object.  So if I had String name = "bob";  could I do something like "name" = "fred" and have that be equivalent to name = "fred" through some type of parsing/conversion or any other way.

Comment: edited my answer... but it's still hard to follow what you're saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a way you're describing what reflection is used for:

You refer to an object's fields and methods by name.

- [Java Reflection](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/index.html)

However, most of the time when people ask a question like this, they're better off solving their problem by re-working their design and taking advantage of data structures like Maps.

---

Here's some code that shows how to create a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) from two arrays:

```
String[] keyArray = { "one", "two", "three" };
String[] valArray = { "foo", "bar", "bazzz" };

// create a new HashMap that maps Strings to Strings

Map<String, String> exampleMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

// create a map from the two arrays above

for (int i = 0; i < keyArray.length; i++) {
    String theKey = keyArray[i];
    String theVal = valArray[i];
    exampleMap.put(theKey, theVal);
}

// print the contents of our new map

for (String loopKey : exampleMap.keySet()) {
    String loopVal = exampleMap.get(loopKey);
    System.out.println(loopKey + ": " + loopVal);
}
```

Here's a link to the [JavaDoc for Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just use a simple hashmap for this?

```
Map<String, String> mapping = new HashMap<String, String>();
mapping.put("fname", "someValue");
...

String value = mapping.get(key); //key could be "fname"
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer.  I am using a hashmap at the moment.  I think I should be using contains() and then setting fname rather than iterating over the whole map since I know the cookie's I'm expecting.  But yes I will accept this. THanks for the swift reply! I think I am preparing for have many many cookies when in reality that is probably quite uncommon.  A better idea would be one cookie and pull the rest of the info from a database based on a username cookie.

Comment: Map has a method named _containsKey_: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsKey%28java.lang.Object%29